# Is the any way to use numbers on list to perform operations?

Tags: python

For a newcomer to python from c++
In python for example, is there a way to get this to substitute in the element in list position f[n-1], perform mathematical operations, and add it to the next element on the list?

```
f = [1, 1-x]
for n in range (1,5):
    f[n+1] = simplify((x*f[n-1])/n)
    print(f[n])
```

Comment: You should avoid modifying a list while iterating over it. Perhaps a list comprehension?

Comment: `f.append(someelement)` will add an element to a list. @PauloScardine, as long as he is using indexes then its fine

Comment: @RNar not if he deletes an element, for example... That is why it is frowned upon in Python.

Comment: oh i thought you meant that it would cause an error such as `for i in l: l.append(x)` would

Comment: Of course you are right, if he is careful he can port "pointer arithmetic" algorithms from C to Python arrays, but it is not idiomatic.

Comment: This question may suffer form the X,Y problem, that is, when the OP wants to solve problem X, but instead of asking about X he is asking about his devised solution Y. Perhaps if you update it to shed more light on the original problem we can point a more idiomatic solution.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the effect you want?  It extends the list, f, one element on each iteration.  I removed the **simplify** call, because I expect that it doesn't really affect your *Python* mechanics question.

```
x = 0.4

f = [1, 1-x]
for n in range(1,5):
    f.append((x*f[n-1]) / n)

print(f)
```

The output from this is

```
[1, 0.6, 0.4, 0.12, 0.053333333333333344, 0.012]
```

---

Now that you've clarified a little, here's a starting point for your string processing.

```
def simplify(expr):
    return expr

f = ["1", "1-x"]
for n in range(1, 5):
    f.append(simplify("x*(" + f[n-1] + ")/n"))
    print(f[n])
```

The output from this is

```
1-x
x*(1)/n
x*(1-x)/n
x*(x*(1)/n)/n
```

This leaves you with a reduced programming problem to attack: how to reduce things such as "x*(x*" to "x**2".  You're tackling a bit of a parsing problem here: you'll likely have to specify a grammar and make a reasonable attack on your coding to get to the next point where we can help.

Comment: What i want is to leave x unknown and make the list go on like [1, 1-x, x-x**2/2, .....]. is that possible?

Comment: Then please finish your posting to reflect the actual problem.  See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  If you're trying to do symbolic representations, you'll need a domain-specific string processor in **simplify**, and your list will need to hold strings, not numeric values.

Comment: @Joe_Rose I'm not sure I understood what you want. How about posting the equivalent solution in C++ so the question is less ambiguous?